# Vertical scroll bar not coming down when searched text goes down the rich text box

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a rich text box.I have added the below code to implement search functionality:

**startindex = rtbContents.Find(txtToSearch, searchStart, searchEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
endindex=txtSearch.Text.Length();
// Highlight the search string
rtbContents.Select(startindex, endindex);**

The problem is when the text it searches goes below i.e beyond the Visible pane of the rich text box, then the vertical scroll bar does not come down automatically.I had to manually drag it down.How do I do that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying css overflow :scroll to your rich textbox